# Using touch events with Createjs / Easeljs

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs, createjs

I'm trying to use touch events with Createjs / Easeljs objects. For example, I'm trying to attach a touchstart and touchmove event using addEventListener.

Touchstart and mousedown seems to work: I'm using a browser and a touch device to test it and it seems to work in both cases.

However, mousemove and touchmove doesn't seem to work. I though it was because I removed the stopPropagation and preventDefault methods, but I saw that Lanny McNie wrote that there is no need to do it in CreateJS [1](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs/1104-prevent-event-propagation).

I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

This is my code:
http://pastebin.com/pqxWLNKG

Regards.

Comment: Assuming it's enabled correctly, I'd suggest setting a breakpoint in the appropriate device specific code and see if it is a browser issue or something else.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, I wish I could, I think that the remote debug console it's not enabled yet.

Comment: Maybe add some logging instead? What device are you connecting?

Comment: @WiredPrairie, I'm using a Keon Geeksphone device. I can use Adb Logcat, but the best I can see is this: http://pastebin.com/CVcC2mxb

Comment: Your device likely hasn't been tested with it... I wonder if it's not sending the events correctly (so maybe it's not a problem with the library as it is with the phone?)

Comment: @WiredPrairie, is there any other way to test the touch event using any other kind of device or emulator? Is there any browser extesion or plugin to transform clicks into touchs?

Comment: Do you have access to an iPad, iPhone, or modern Android device? You could get the Android emulator as part of the Android development kit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the Touch class included with EaselJS to enable multi-touch - which translate into normal EaselJS mousedown/mousemove events. Check out the DragAndDrop demo: http://www.createjs.com/demos/easeljs/draganddrop

```
createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
```

Cheers.

Comment: thanks a lot. Is there any way to replace onPress, onMouseMove, onMouseOver and onMouseOut with addEventListener If I do createjs.Touch.enable(stage);

Or does the Touch class only enable multi touch for that onAction methods?

Comment: The touch class just proxies the existing interactions. The onAction callbacks are all deprecated - the event model is encouraged!

Comment: This was great! Until I saw this I was trying to use fastclick.js and couldn't accomplish what I was looking to do. Thanks!