# "mousedown" event be triggered in misplaced region in createjs

Tags: javascript, createjs

This is a game imitating Chrome's offline game;

demo:
http://chendind.com/createjs/JumpDragon/index.html

(-W:jump, -S:bend)

Please look at my game screenshot
[game screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJYKL.png)
, when you are in a mobile device, you can't restart game by touching the "restart" button's right region, but the green region marked in this screenshot;

relative code is in JumpDragon.js, line 117;

simply like this:

```
restart.on("mousedown",function(){
    restartGame();
});
```

My question is why there is a deviation?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: i found that css-transform influence createjs's position system;because if i remove css-transform, it performs well;   look at improved version http://chendind.com/createjs/JumpDragon/test.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have answered your own question.

It would be a good idea to take a look at this post: [Using touch events with Createjs / Easeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166619/using-touch-events-with-createjs-easeljs)

And also the Touch class in CreateJS: http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Touch.html